# How far ahead of the wing should a propeller be located for a UAV?

Tags: propeller, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

This question is asked in context of a fixed wing, Unmanned Aerial Vehicle (UAV), with a wing span of about 5m (16ft).

How far ahead of the wing leading edge should the propeller be located?

The propwash should have minimal effect on stability and should not adversely affect the airflow over the wing.

Can propwash be useful?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Do you want the props as close to the wing as aerodynamically possible, or as far from the wing as possible?

Comment: Are you designing a twin? Because with single engine you don't have much choice: you must place the prop at the nose (or tail; pusher is a choice you do have) and the wing according to the centre of gravity.

Comment: Why does it have to be ahead of the leading edge - I can think of a few where it is to the rear.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: I am only looking for a tractor configuration, for now. It is a single prop not twin. So, I want to know what should be the distance between the propeller and wing leading edge so as to minimise the disadvantages of propwash. Is there any rule of thumb or empirical relation or any relevant material on this? Re~ 5e5.

Comment: what would be the changes if a twin prop is used? Span wise location will also come into the picture but i dont think there will be any cancellation of propwash taking place. All the views will help. Thanks.

Comment: @Dcode any update on how this turned out? what you discovered regarding optimal prop distance and flight characteristics, noise, etc

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/aerospace/comments/4dd98q/distance_between_propeller_and_leading_edge_of/ also based on measuring images of random prop planes, the distance between the prop and the leading edge of the wing seems to be between around 8% and 15% of the total wingspan. 8% for larger planes